# nvidia GPU: additional driver is missing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have two Nvidia GPUs (GPU0: 1080Ti, GPU1: 1060).

```
sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:119 memory:d8000000-d8ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:d9000000-d907ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:42:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

As you can see, the additional driver is only available for the second GPU.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The driver is installed and is available for both GPU's as you can see in your terminal output.

Both GPU are using `nvidia` kernel module.

There is nothing to worry about.

The GUI tool is not too good generally and is not designed to deal with more than one Nvidia GPU.